# Connect Android app to phpmyadmin - could not connect error

Tags: java, android, mysql

Hi I'm creating an android app and need to connect to phpmyadmin, I get following error in Logcat ..... com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MysqlNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server

My MainActivity.java class

```
  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.view.Menu;
  import android.view.View;


 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.KwikFit2.MESSAGE";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void sendMessage(View view) {
    DatabaseConnection dbcon = new DatabaseConnection();
    dbcon.connectionCreate("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/diss", "root", "");

    System.out.println("got here");
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayWelcomeActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

My DatabaseConnection.java

```
package com.example.kwikfit2;
import java.sql.*;


public class DatabaseConnection {

public Connection connectionCreate(String url, String user, String password){
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,password);
        System.out.println("Connection Established");
        return con;
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }return null;
}
```

}

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: Post title is misleading. You are not connecting to PHPMyAdmin, you are connecting to a MySQL database. Have you made 100% sure that username (root) and password (empty, in your example) are correct and that connections from localhost are allowed to localhost? Maybe check with a MySQL client first if you can connect to the database with it.

Answer (score 0):

As Shihan pointed out, you don't connect to phpmyadmin. It's just a web-based tool used to manage Mysql databases.

Your code assumes that you are running MySQL in localhost which would be your android device and I seriously doubt that. Quick google search didn't find any info about Android version of the MySQL server. You should connect to the actual server that's really running the MySQL database. Also note that usually MySQL is configured to only allow connections from localhost by default.

On Android you don't really use jdbc at all. It would be better to have a RESTful service on the server and Android would just use that interface through HTTP to communicate with the server.

You should check out tutorials about SQLite and see if it would be the answer to your problem. It's an embedded database that's used in many Android applications.

Comment: Hi thank you both for replying and I apologise for the misleading title. I have now tried implementing a SQLite database by following this tutorial (I copied and pasted the content .... link is below) however I keep getting this error in eclipse "The method getAuthor() is undefined for the type Book" on all the get methods. Once again thank you for any advice and help in advance. hmkcode.com/android-simple-sqlite-database-tutorial

Comment: You should add those methods to the Book class yourself. That's so basic stuff so the one who made the tutorial just left it out. It seems that you still have much to learn and I would stay away from databases until you are more familiar with the basics of programming.